# WebGL got weird drawing(loop not closed) with gl.TRIANGLES

Tags: webgl

I am trying to use gl.TRIANGLES to draw an "I" shape, I have meshed it in 24 triangles, the first 22 gives me this shape, however, whenever I added the last two triangle vertices, I got this weird shape, I double-checked the coordinates of the last two triangles, and they are correct, so not sure what could be wrong in my code, which I pasted it here.

shape "I" with 22 triangles

[image: shape "I" with 22 triangles]

weird shape "I" with 24 triangles

[image: weird shape "I" with 24 triangles]

```html
/**
 * @file A simple WebGL example drawing a triangle with colors
 * @author Eric Shaffer <shaffer1@eillinois.edu>  
 */

/** @global The WebGL context */
var gl;

/** @global The HTML5 canvas we draw on */
var canvas;

/** @global A simple GLSL shader program */
var shaderProgram;

/** @global The WebGL buffer holding the triangle */
var vertexPositionBuffer;

/** @global The WebGL buffer holding the vertex colors */
var vertexColorBuffer;

/**
 * Creates a context for WebGL
 * @param {element} canvas WebGL canvas
 * @return {Object} WebGL context
 */
function createGLContext(canvas) {
  var context = null;
  context = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
  if (context) {
    context.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    context.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
  } else {
    alert("Failed to create WebGL context!");
  }
  return context;
}

/**
 * Loads Shaders
 * @param {string} id ID string for shader to load. Either vertex shader/fragment shader
 */
function loadShaderFromDOM(id) {
  var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
  
  // If we don't find an element with the specified id
  // we do an early exit 
  if (!shaderScript) {
    return null;
  }
    
  var shaderSource = shaderScript.text;
 
  var shader;
  if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
 
  gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
 
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    return null;
  } 
  return shader;
}

/**
 * Setup the fragment and vertex shaders
 */
function setupShaders() {
  vertexShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-vs");
  fragmentShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-fs");
  
  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Failed to setup shaders");
  }

  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
  shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
  shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");  
    
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);
}

/**
 * Populate buffers with data
 */
function setupBuffers() {
  vertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionBuffer);
  var triangleVertices = [      
        /*triangle*/
        -0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
        -0.6, -0.9, 0.0,
         0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        -0.6, -0.9, 0.0,
         0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
         0.6, -0.9, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
         0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
         0.7, -0.5, 0.0,
         0.6, -0.6, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
         0.6, -0.9, 0.0,
         0.6, -0.6, 0.0,
         0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
         0.6, -0.6, 0.0,
         0.7, -0.5, 0.0,
         0.3, -0.5, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
         0.6, -0.6, 0.0,
         0.3, -0.5, 0.0,
         0.2, -0.6, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
         0.3, -0.5, 0.0,
         0.2, -0.6, 0.0,
         0.3,  0.5, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
         0.2, -0.6, 0.0,
         0.3,  0.5, 0.0,
         0.2,  0.6, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        0.3,  0.5, 0.0,
        0.2,  0.6, 0.0,
        0.6,  0.6, 0.0, 
        /*triangle*/
        0.3,  0.5, 0.0,
        0.6,  0.6, 0.0,
        0.7,  0.5, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        0.6,  0.6, 0.0,
        0.7,  0.5, 0.0,
        0.7,  1.0, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        0.6,  0.6, 0.0,
        0.7,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.6,  0.9, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        0.7,  1.0, 0.0,
        0.6,  0.9, 0.0,
        -0.6, 0.9, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        0.7,  1.0, 0.0,
        -0.6, 0.9, 0.0,
        -0.7, 1.0, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        -0.7,  1.0, 0.0, 
        -0.7,  0.5, 0.0, 
        -0.6,  0.9, 0.0,
        /*triangle*/
        -0.7,  0.5, 0.0, 
        -0.6,  0.6, 0.0, 
        -0.6,  0.9, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.7,  0.5, 0.0, 
        -0.6,  0.6, 0.0,
        -0.3,  0.5, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.6,  0.6, 0.0,
        -0.3,  0.5, 0.0,
        -0.2,  0.6, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.3,  0.5, 0.0,
        -0.2,  0.6, 0.0,
        -0.3, -0.5, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.2,  0.6, 0.0,
        -0.3, -0.5, 0.0,
        -0.2, -0.6, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.3, -0.5, 0.0,
        -0.2, -0.6, 0.0,
        -0.7, -0.5, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.2, -0.6, 0.0,
        -0.7, -0.5, 0.0,
        -0.6, -0.6, 0,0,    
         /*triangle*/
        -0.7, -0.5, 0.0,
        -0.6, -0.6, 0,0,
        -0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.6, -0.6, 0,0,
        -0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
        -0.6, -0.9, 0.0,
  ];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  vertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
  vertexPositionBuffer.numberOfItems = 72;
    
  vertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexColorBuffer);
  var colors = [
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    ];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  vertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
  vertexColorBuffer.numItems = 72;  
    
}

/**
 * Draw model...render a frame
 */
function draw() { 
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight); 
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, 
                         vertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexColorBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, 
                            vertexColorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexPositionBuffer.numberOfItems);
}

/**
 * Startup function called from html code to start program.
 */
 function startup() {
  
  console.log("No bugs so far...");
  canvas = document.getElementById("myGLCanvas");
  gl = createGLContext(canvas);
  setupShaders(); 
  setupBuffers();
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  draw();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 places in your vertex data were you have `0,0` instead of `0.0`

```
 var triangleVertices = [      


        ...

         /*triangle*/
        -0.2, -0.6, 0.0,
        -0.7, -0.5, 0.0,
        -0.6, -0.6, 0,0,   // <==---    
         /*triangle*/
        -0.7, -0.5, 0.0,
        -0.6, -0.6, 0,0,   // <==--- 
        -0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
         /*triangle*/
        -0.6, -0.6, 0,0,   // <==---
        -0.7, -1.0, 0.0,
        -0.6, -0.9, 0.0,
  ];
```

Comment: thanks for the help, hardly see those difference for a fresh, really appreciate